# How to stick element to bottom of its container if the container is scrollable?

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed, absolute

My problem is that the green child element does not stick the bottom even though it's positioned absolute with bottom:0.

The hello world text in the container is making the container scrollable and making the green element not able to stick to the bottom.

Edit: The container needs position: fixed. (Its a shopping cart modal).

```css
.container {
 background: red;
 height: 100%;
 width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: auto;
}

.child {
 background: green;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>

v
<div class='child'>
asdf
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wrap the whole container in another element with `position:relative` and place the absolute element in it.

Comment: The container should have `position: relative` to let the child make use of `position: absolute`.

Comment: So you want the "asdf" so always stay at the bottom of the list, and scroll normally through the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `position: sticky` on the child works for you? This way it will not cover the bottom of the container which you would have to take care of with `padding` when using `position: absolute`.

```css
.container {
 background: red;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
 width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: auto;
}

.container__inner {
  flex: 1
}

.child {
 background: green;
 position: sticky;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='container__inner'>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>
<div>hello world </div>

v
</div>
<div class='child'>
asdf
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when there is no "hello world" content in the parent container, the green "asdf" moves up and no longer sticks to the bottom of the container.

Comment: I edited the example to accomplish what you want hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so you've solved the problem of the green footer sticking to the bottom when theres no content in the parent. However now the green footer looks like its height is squished around the text. I forgot to mention that the footer is supposed to be 80px (or 11%) in height. Also when you scroll to the bottom, theres a gap between the footer and the bottom of the container that appears.

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky` does the trick.
However, you also need to add `bottom: 8px` to prevent it from being half hidden

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>
  <div>hello world </div>

  <div class='child'>
    footer preview
  </div>
  <div style='background: green'>rest of footer<br> &nbsp</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when there is no "hello world" content in the parent container, the green footer moves up and no longer sticks to the bottom of the container.

Comment: I did not know you wanted that. I will try to see if I can fix that

Answer (score 1):

use `position:sticky` and also give some bottom margin so that the element won't hide.